# Ошибка в SQL запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго вечера! Создал две таблицы в БД MySQL с помощью phpmyadmin и выбрал export для создания SQL запроса. Выполнив этот SQL запрос в phpmyadmin, всё работает, а в своём коде не работает, показывает ошибку :

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_quick_polls` ( `pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCR' at line 2*

код :

```
mysql_query("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_quick_polls` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quest` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `tansw` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'one',
  UNIQUE KEY `pid` (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_quick_polls_vnts` (
  `vnt_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `cnts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `vnt_id` (`vnt_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
echo mysql_error();
```

Если разделить на два запроса - иногда работает. Часть кода для подключения, выбора базы опустил, права на запись есть, баз не существует, слов не попалось зарезервированных. Уже до одури, видимо я сегодня переработал, и уже голова не соображает, обращаюсь к вам за помощью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расширение mysql не позволяет выполнять несколько запросов за один раз. Разбейте запрос на два и выполните их по отдельности. Либо почитайте про [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Спасибо большое, пожалуй, спать пойду, на сегодня хватит. )